# test fails toThrow

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, jestjs

I am having a problem with testing my application (for studies) for when there is an equal category name in the database. Although the category is not added to the table again, the test does not pass.

When I add a new category that is not in the bank, it says Matcher Error: the received value must be a function but what to expect cannot test a variable?

And I don't know where I might be going wrong

class DAO

```
export default class CategoryDAO {
  constructor(conn) {
    this._conn = conn
  }
  async add(category) {
    if (!(category instanceof Category)) {
      throw new Error("The object is not of type category")
    }
    try {
      const categories = await this._conn.query(`SELECT * FROM category`)
      
      if (categories.some(c => c.name === category.name)) {
        throw new Error("The category has already been registered")
      }
      await this._conn.query(`INSERT INTO category (name) VALUES (?)`, [category.name])
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error)
    }
  }
}
```

Test

```
describe("Tests for Class Category", () => {
  let conn = new Connection()

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await conn.conect()
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await conn.close();
  })

  it("Creating author successfully", async () => {
    const categoryDAO = new CategoryDAO(conn)
    const category = new Category("Devops")
    await categoryDAO.add(category)
    expect(category.name).toBeDefined()
  })

  it("Add must throw error when another author is registered", async () => {
    const categoryDAO = new CategoryDAO(conn)
    const category = new Category("Devops")
    await categoryDAO.add(category)
    expect( category).toThrow(new Error(`The category has already been registered`))
  })
```

Log

```
Tests for Class Category › Add must throw error when another author is registered

    Error: The category has already been registered

      17 |       await this._conn.query(`INSERT INTO category (name) VALUES (?)`, [category.name])
      18 |     } catch (error) {
    > 19 |       throw new Error(error)
         |             ^
      20 |     }
      21 |   }
      22 | }
```

Comment: `expect(category)` doesn't do anything. It just looks at a variable. Do you mean to do something with it? Did you mean `expect(await categoryDAO.add(category)).toThrow(...)`?

Comment: you might have to use a arrow function for that

Comment: HI, @tadman, Thank you for your answer.I had already tried this way but I get the same error 

```expect(received).toThrow(expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a function
    Received has value: undefined

      25 |     const category = new Category("Devopss")
      26 |     //await categoryDAO.add(category)
expect(await categoryDAO.add(category)).toThrow(new Error(`The category has already been registered`))```

Comment: I think Daniel has the right idea.

Comment: But @DanielA.White and tadman I'm already in an arrow function, doesn't?

Comment: @tadman about the replay above

Comment: Can you use `async` functions in `expect` in your test framework? Worth checking that first.

Comment: yes, @tadman! [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#asyncawait)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but this is based on the pattern in the documentation you linked to:

```
await expect(categoryDAO.add(category)).rejects.toThrow({
  ... // Your error.
});
```

Comment: Thanks! @tadman I tested it so many times with rejects and expect, but expect did nothing with category only. It worked with `toThrow`, this way: `await expect(categoryDAO.add(category)).rejects.toThrow(`The category has already been registered`)`